# PowerShell Send new Lines to Slack

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to send new lines added to a log file to slack if they have a certain word(s) in it - see in slack if I have errors.

What I hoped would work is:

```
$message = Get-Content '\\path\to\file.log' -Wait -Tail 0 | Select-String -Pattern 'ERROR'

foreach($line in $message) { Send-SlackMsg -Text "$($line)" -Channel $channel }
```

Sadly, it does not. I've replaced Send-SlackMsg with Write-Host just to see if that is the issue but it's not.

```
Get-Content '\\path\to\file.log' -Wait -Tail 0 | Select-String -Pattern 'ERROR'
```

Works like a charm in my console.

How can I make PowerShell perform an action when a new line appears and it matches the pattern?

Comment: Use `|ForEach-Object {...}` after `Select-String` instead of assigning to `$message` - otherwise the first line is just going to block forever because of the `-Wait` switch

Comment: And what is the var which represents the new line? $line did not work.

Comment: With a `ForEach-Object` the current item in the pipeline is represented by `$_`.

Comment: thanks! kinda new to powershell, sorry for the silly questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comment from Mathias, you could use `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-Content '\\path\to\file.log' -Wait -Tail 0 | Select-String -Pattern 'ERROR' | ForEach-Object { Send-SlackMsg -Text $_ -Channel $channel }
```

The problem with your code was that because of the `-Wait` switch the code was never proceeding past the `$message =` line. However `ForEach-Object` processes objects via the pipeline, so as soon as a new line is written to the file which matches 'ERROR' it is passed down the pipeline and in to the `ForEach-Object`.